# (Proof check) Let $R$ be a UFD. If $f \in R[X]$ is irreducible then $f \in K[X]$ is irreducible for $K$ the fraction field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I understand that this is Gauss' Lemma but I want to see if my version of the proof was correct.

Let $f \in K[X]$ is reducible. Assume FTSOC that $f$ is irreducible in $R[X].$ We have that $f = g_1g_2\ldots g_k$ for $g_i$ prime in $K[X].$ Now let $\alpha_i$ be the lcm of the denominators of each coefficient in $g_i.$ Let $\alpha = \prod_i \alpha_i.$ We have that $\alpha f = \prod_i (\alpha_i g_i) \in R[X].$ Since $f$ is irreducible in a UFD, it is prime. Hence, for some $j, f \mid \alpha_j g_j.$ Let $fk = \alpha_j g_j.$ Clearly $k$ cannot be a unit in $K$ otherwise $g_j$ would be a unit multiple of $f$ in $K[X].$ Hence, $g_j$ is not irreducible. Contradiction.

The last step seems a bit iffy to me. Any help would be appreciated.